# How do programmatically filter out certain packages with Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have:

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = context.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.detachAndStopAllAppenders();
root.addAppender(consoleAppender);
root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

However I would like to setup setup a different logging level for certain packages. So for example I would like to setup the level to be `Level.WARN` for the package `com.mypackage.*` How do I do this?

Comment: [LOGBack Filters](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html)

Comment: I looked at that link and all the information and examples are through config files and not programatically ;)

Comment: I'd also look at [`Appender`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/Appender.html), it has a [`addFilter`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/FilterAttachable.html#addFilter(ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter)) method. The point of the previous comment was to provide information about how to write filter.  I've never used LOGBack, but all I did was look into the the above link, and JavaDocs, which seeded the basic idea

Comment: I actually did look at that but the javadocs are very weak. I also tried to google with addFilter but the results were poor and nothing seemed to fit. In other words there wasn't much in terms of javadocs or search results for this so I don't know if that's in the right direction or going down the wrong rabbit hole :(